# How to properly choose between old, deprecated and non-deprecated methods?

Tags: javascript, methods, binding, this, deprecated

I'm working on a patch to piece of code which creates an AudioContext, then wants to create  the WebAudio API. Specifically, it

```
function(...) {
  var AudioContext = AudioContext || webkitAudioContext;

  return {

    /* ... */

    init: function() {
      var self = this;

      this.ac = new AudioContext();
      /* createJavaScriptNode is deprecated, doesn't exist anymore in newer Chromium, */
      /* must use createScriptProcessor there. */
      this.anode = this.ac.createJavaScriptNode(this.bufferSize, this.inputChannels,
                                                 this.outputChannels);
      /* ... */
    },
    /* ... */
  };
  /* ... */
};
```

The idea is to support browsers which implement the deprecated API but don't yet support the newer one.

Choosing between `AudioContext` and `webkitAudioContext` isn't the problem, because they're both constructors.

I know I cant use the same idiom to choose between `createJavaScriptNode` and `createScriptProcessor`, because they're both methods. 
How can I best do this without too much code bloat, i.e. creating another local variable and messing around with bind()?

I am thinking of:

```
this.anode = (this.ac.createJavaScriptNode || this.ac.createScriptProcessor)(this.bufferSize, this.inputChannels,
                                                     this.outputChannels);
```

I haven't tried it yet, for I'm worried that this way of calling the method may lose the context.
Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Chris Wilson's monkey patch:  https://github.com/cwilso/AudioContext-MonkeyPatch

This should take care of most (all?) cases for you.